# habtm and nested form result to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 3 models, Product, Variation and Color. I'm using the nested_form gem.

```
Product has_many :variations

Variation belongs_to :product
Variation has_and_belongs_to_many :colors

Color has_and_belongs_to_many :variations
```

Through Product form I have nested_form for Variations. I want to associate colors through checkbox but receive `undefined local variable or method "color_ids"`

Product model

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  1.times { @product.variations.build }
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  ...
end
```

My form //edited//

```
<%= nested_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="inline-form">
  <%= f.fields_for :variations %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a variation", :variations %></p>
</div>

<div class="actions">
 <%= submit_or_cancel(f) %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And nested form is a basic table with

```
<table id="new_item">
  <tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40 %></td>
    <td><% for color in Color.all %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'variation[color_ids][]', color.id, variation.color_ids.include?(color.id), :id => dom_id(color) %><%= label_tag dom_id(color), color.name, :class => "check_box_label" %>
    <% end %>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your issue is the part of the form doing `color_ids.include?(color.id)`. I'd need to see the rest of your form erb to tell you how to fix it.

It's going to be something like `variation.color_ids`.

Another thing to note, that style of for loop is odd to see in typical/idiomatic ruby.

This is more typical:

```
<% Color.all.each do |color| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'variation[color_ids][]', color.id, color_ids.include?(color.id), :id => dom_id(color) %><%= label_tag dom_id(color), color.name, :class => "check_box_label" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right the problem is here `color_ids.include?(color.id)`. I updated my question with full form. I tried variation.color_ids too but I get `undefined local variable or method `variation' for #<#<Class:0x007fc9b52da7b8>:0x007fc9b52bfeb8>`

Comment: I looked at the code for nested_form, but couldn't figure out what you're doing. I'm not sure where the table is in relation to the form. so there I can't tell what would be setting up your context. 

It looks like this is just for new variations. Would they even have a set of associated colors yet? You may be able to replace `variation.color_ids.include?(color.id)` with `false` if this is the case.